# Building apk gives error Could not create service of type DefaultUserHomeScopedCompileCaches... in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am building a basic **Flutter** app but it gives an error.

**Error Message:**

```
Could not create service of type DefaultUserHomeScopedCompileCaches using UserHomeScopeServices.createCompileCaches()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do File > Invalidate caches and restart.then try to run .
```